# Change text of selected option only while selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, django

I have a select box that allows the user to select a category for an article of clothing. The categories can have sub categories, so in order to display that hierarchy, I write the options like this:

```
Category Name
&nbsp;&nbsp;&#x251c;&#x2500; Sub-category name
```

which looks like this:

Category Name

├─ Sub-category name

Unfortunately, when the user selects a sub-category, then the text that shows in the select box  includes the structure characters. How do I only display the category name when an option is selected, but keep the structure HTML when they change options? Is there a better way to show the hierarchy of categories within the options? Optgroups don't work for me, because the user needs to be able to select the top-level categories also.

Here's what it looks like now.

http://jsfiddle.net/K6yfp/

Comment: Please add a JS Fiddle!

Comment: Don't use a select element.

Comment: JS Fiddle added. @epascarello what would I add instead? The site needs to be mobile friendly.

Comment: you may change to use optgroup tag.

Comment: optgroups wouldn't fix the issue, because I need the top-level categories to also be selectable options.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are looking for `optgroup`

```
<select>
  <optgroup label="Swedish Cars">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="German Cars">
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/K6yfp/3/)

Comment: Optgroups *look* the way I need, but they aren't selectable. In this example, I would need "Sweedish Cars" and "German Cars" to also be selectable.

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with a simple solution but could not workout more on it. Hope you will find it helpful.

**HTML**

```
<select id="Categories">
    <option value="Shoes">Shoes</option>
    <option value="Sneakers">&nbsp;&nbsp;&#x251c;&#x2500;Sneakers</option>
</select>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var SelectedCategory = $('#Categories').find('option:selected').val();
    $('#Categories').bind("change",function() {
        $(this).find('option:selected').attr('label',$(this).find('option:selected').val());
        SelectedCategory = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
        $(this).blur();
    });

    $('#Categories').focus(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(this).find('option:selected').removeAttr('label');
    }).blur(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(this).find('option:selected').attr('label',$(this).find('option:selected').val());
    });
});
```

Note: Do not forget to include the **jQuery** Library.

Check the [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K6yfp).